# Effects of installing a package without restarting R first?

Tags: r, rstudio

Sometimes when installing a library with `install.packages()`, RStudio displays an informative pop up:

[image]

After selecting 'Yes', occasionally, this falls into a loop where R restarts, RStudio tries to install the package, RStudio provides the same pop up again, and so the cycle continues.

After a couple of attempts, I click 'No', and install the package without restarting R.

#### Question

What are the specific effects of selecting 'No', that is, installing a currently loaded package *without* restarting R first?

Comment: Packages that include shared-objects (`.so`, `.dll`, `.lib`) can cause problems. That is, when R dynamically links to a shared object (which is their intent), then over-writing/replacing that shared object is often not possible (because it has an open file-descriptor internally). Because of this, updating some packages without restarting R will often either (1) cause the installation to fail, or (2) cause unexpected results such as still referencing the previous-version shared object.

Comment: @r2evans great knowledge. In the case of (2), is it true that **if** the package installs successfully (as far as we can tell), and **if** it loads successfully, then it worked? (or could things be failing silently that we just don't know about)

Comment: I can't say without knowing more, but a simple heuristic I've found is that if there is not a `libs` directory (meaning no compiled shared objects) in the package directory (under one of `.libPaths()`), then it likely reinstalled just fine.