# could not find function "left_join" in R

Tags: r

Can you please help me ?

I am getting the error message

> "Error in left_join(raw_data_2, mapping_file, by = "key_4") : 
>     could not find function "left_join".

I was able to run the same program few days back. I have uninstalled and installed R and R Studio both.
But still it is not working.

Please help me..!

Comment: If you don't have `dplyr` installed. install it via `install.packages('dplyr')` and do `library(dplyr)` before using `left_join`.

Comment: Use `library(dplyr)` if you already downloaded the package.

Comment: getting some weird error. after runiing the library(dplyr),                                       
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.4 is required

Comment: hi, can someone please help me as I am not able to understand this error

Comment: Eventually update the packages **vctrs** and **dplyr**

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451908/tidyverse-not-loaded-it-says-namespace-vctrs-0-2-0-is-already-loaded-but/60452823#60452823

Answer (score 1):

Join functions are come with 'dplyr' package in R. This error occurs due to inactivate library 'dplyr'. You need to activate this library using library(dplyr) before your code. If it's not installed, first need to install using install.packages('dplyr').

```
#install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

#your code up to creating raw_data_2 and mapping_file
left_join(raw_data_2, mapping_file, by = "key_4")
```