# Why does ocurr this Error in library(tidyverse)?

Tags: r, tidyverse

When downloading the package "*tidyverse*" I run into this error after running the `library(tidyverse)`:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in
> loadNamespace (i, c (lib.loc, .libPaths ()), versionCheck = vI [[i]]):
> namespace ‘dplyr’ 0.8.5 is already loaded, but> = 1.0.0 is required

Comment: The error message seems rather clear: The library `dplyr` is required in at least 1.0.0, but an older version is already loaded (apparently earlier). Make sure nothing loads dplyr before loading tidyverse or alternative make sure that *if* it's loaded it's with a sufficiently high version number.

Comment: [This question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451908/tidyverse-not-loaded-it-says-namespace-vctrs-0-2-0-is-already-loaded-but).

Comment: Thank you Joachim! I noticed the error and needed to download in "Check for Package update" some packages and now they are all installed in the library. The order too is important. Thank for your attention.