# Can't load tidyverse package

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am able to install the tidyverse package, but am unable to load it. When I try to load it the following error pops up:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling "cli".

Comment: Your error seems specific i.e. the version 3.3.0 is needed, but you have 3.2.0.  I would recommend to install and load individual packages i.e. `library(dplyr);library(tidyr)` instead of tidyverse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tidyverse not loaded, it says "namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451908/tidyverse-not-loaded-it-says-namespace-vctrs-0-2-0-is-already-loaded-but)

Comment: What happened exactly when you tried uninstalling and reinstalling "cli"? Did you get different errors? Since you already have "cli" loaded, be to restart R to unload everything, then run `install.packages("cli")` to update that package before anything else is loaded.