# In R, how to override current package requirements?

Tags: r, package, tidyverse

In tidyverse, dependence on vctrs is one of the first package dependencies in my experience that will *prevent* you from executing legacy code. For instance, see an example of the error here:

[tidyverse not loaded, it says "namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451908/tidyverse-not-loaded-it-says-namespace-vctrs-0-2-0-is-already-loaded-but)

Working in science and interfacing with regulatory agencies, we have always made the case that R code could be loaded into prior versions and executed so that with any given dataset, we can employ an exact copy of a legacy R engine, and get identical results. Luckily none of our code has used tidyverse.

However, is this argument not true? And if not, how could I force an old tidyverse to load successfully with an old vctrs package without giving an error?

Comment: You get that error because you updated a package to a newer version that depended on vctrs and the updated package requires a newer version of vctrs to work. If you never updated that other dependency, you would not have got that message. So if you keep track of what versions of package where installed when you ran the code originally, and reinstall those exact versions later, then everything will be reproducible. Package like [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html) help with that. This is not a problem specific to tidyverse.

Comment: You can do that, with or without tidyverse. You just need to make sure that all your packages (and all the ones they depend on) are compatible. Microsoft used to maintain MRAN, which had daily CRAN snapshots so you could, e.g., do a fresh install of all packages in their current state as of any particular day. Microsoft ended support, but I think you can now use [Posit Package Manager](https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/) for the same purpose.

Comment: What you are describing is not specific to tidyverse or to R for that matter. In other programming languages, there are notions of fixed dependencies such as python's `requirements.txt`, where specific versions are listed as required. MrFlick suggested `renv`, which is one way to do the same thing in R. This is also a problem in basic web design, where upgrading one javascript library will break things unless many/all others are upgraded too. I understand the pain associated with this, it is a known problem with all sorts of "techniques" to mitigate, some more formal/robust than others.

Comment: I'll second GregorThomas's recommenation for Posit's PM; it supports "packages as of date" mentality, which allows you to fix _all_ packages to no more recent than a certain date, realizing that this comes with risks (of known and not-yet-fixed bugs or security holes) as well. Your linked error is a known and frequent question, with known remedies. If these comments don't resolve it for you, I suggest you move this discussion to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com or similar where _design_ principles are more applicable.